# objective c NSXMLParser delegate class doesn't trigger delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

i following simple [tutorial](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) on the web to parse xml with NSXMLParser. 
the delegate object does init , but never trigger the NSXMLParser delegate methods . 
what im doing wrong ? 
im using GNUSetup on windows .

here is where i call the parser :

```
-(BOOL) loadXmlPath :(NSString*)filePathXml:(NSString*) filePathWrite
{
    if([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePathXml] == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",filePathXml);       
        NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathXml]; 
        NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
        if(nsXmlParser)
        {
             NSLog(@"done setup parser");
        }
        else
        {
             NSLog(@"fail setup parser");
        }
        // create and init our delegate
        XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
        [nsXmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; // We don't care about namespaces
    [nsXmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; //
    [nsXmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; // We just want data, no other stuff
    // set delegate
    [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    // parsing...
    BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse];
      // test the result
    if (success) {
         NSLog(@"parsing document!");
         // get array of users here
    } else {
        if ([nsXmlParser parserError]) {
            NSError *err = [nsXmlParser parserError];
            NSString *serror = [err localizedDescription];
            NSLog(@"Error parsing document!%@\n",serror);
        }
        NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");
    }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

XmlParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLParser : NSObject 
{
    NSXMLParser *parser;


}
-(XMLParser *) initXMLParser;
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;

@end
```

XmlParser.m

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
@implementation XMLParser



- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser {
   self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"Init xml parser");

  return self;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

     NSLog(@"Enter parser 1");
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",elementName);

        return;
    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"person"] ) {

        return;
    }

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"lastName"] ) {

        return;
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"Enter parser 2");

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"Enter parser 3");

    if (( [elementName isEqualToString:@"addresses"]) ||
        ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"address"] )) return;

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"person"] ) {

        return;
    }

}

@end
```

its never reach to the parser methods . but its do reach to the initXMLParser .
what do i do wrong here ?
also im getting in the :[err localizedDescription]
this msg :

> NSXMLParserErrorDomain 3

what does  it mean ?

Comment: XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
        [nsXmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO]; // We don't care about namespaces
    [nsXmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO]; //
    [nsXmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO]; // We just want data, no other stuff
    // set delegate
    [nsXmlParser setDelegate:self]; // instead of parser put it to self
    // parsing...
    BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse];

Answer (score 0):

In your `XmlParser.h` you need to show that you implement the parser delegate

This line

```
@interface XMLParser : NSObject
```

should be

```
@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

**EDIT:**

Your init is also wrong, it should be as follows

```
- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser {
  self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"Init xml parser");

  return self;
}
```

You've forgotten to assign the value of `[super init]` to self

Comment: i added this but still it failes , reach to the :

Comment: I've edited the code, you are not assigning a value to `self`

Comment: i edit the code ( look in the original msg ) 
also added error check and im getting :
NSXMLParserErrorDomain 3 .. what does it mean ?

Comment: the problem is i had : <?xml version="1.0"?>
as top tag